# Support Vector Regression vs Support Vector Machine for Classification

Tags: svm

I am reading about this topic and these is one point i do not understand

[image]

in the classification Epsilon which is the width of yellow area should be ***maximized***

we are trying to find the hyperplane where the yellow area is as wide as possible. to separate 2 classes

while in regression method it is the opposite the yellow area should be ***minimized*** we are trying to find a hyperplane where the yellow area is as narrow as possible. to include as much data as possible in that epsilon area.

if what I am saying is right that means the regression case does now separate 2 classes as the right or the left of hyperplane does not make any difference.

how can we apply the same equation for both !!

[image]

Comment: I do not think that we actually do have the same equations for both cases... the one you put there is the one for the regression case... it literally sais (up to some math errors) that |prediction - actual value| should be $<\epsilon$. For classification however, we want the sign of $w x_i + b$ be positive for some $x_i$ and negative for others... we can summarize this as $y_i( wx_i + b) \geq 1$, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine